# Why will Google Custom Search API not work from localhost (WAMP, XAMPP) but is OK on a University Server?

Tags: api, search, localhost, wamp

Basically I am working on a meta search engine and have BING and Blekko APIs working fine on localhost (WAMP and XAMPP) but Google Custom Search won't play ball. Now Google will work just fine on a university server, so it's NOT a simple code issue. I'm guessing either Google doesn't want me using a localhost, or the localhosts (WAMP or XAMPP) require a tuning. Anyone who has any knowledge about this must be a web legend. Cheers.

Comment: The university server is probably accessible outside of the network while your localhost is not. There is probably a callback to the URL you've given (localhost/something) which Google's servers cannot resolve since "localhost" doesn't help them find your computer.

Comment: Thanks Sarah, I just ran the curl_error($ch) function and get this message: Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: Ok, this issue is solved by placing:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
Prior to the function call to curl_exec($ch);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, this issue is solved by placing: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); Prior to the function call to curl_exec($ch)

Comment: why not give credit to the other answer, since his was two days before...

Answer (score 7):

As the SSL certificate is not there in local we should add the below code to fix the problem:

Before the function call to

> curl_exec($ch);

add the below line:

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);